# How to get the ThreadPoolExecutor to increase threads to max before queueing?

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue, threadpoolexecutor

I've been frustrated for some time with the default behavior of `ThreadPoolExecutor` which backs the `ExecutorService` thread-pools that so many of us use.  To quote from the Javadocs:

> If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created **only if the queue is full**.

What this means is that if you define a thread pool with the following code, it will *never* start the 2nd thread because the `LinkedBlockingQueue` is unbounded.

```
ExecutorService threadPool =
   new ThreadPoolExecutor(1 /*core*/, 50 /*max*/, 60 /*timeout*/,
      TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(/* unlimited queue*/));
```

Only if you have a *bounded* queue and the queue is *full* are any threads above the core number started.  I suspect a large number of junior Java multithreaded programmers are unaware of this behavior of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Now I have specific use case where this is not-optimal.  I'm looking for ways, without writing my own TPE class, to work around it.

My requirements are for a web service that is making call-backs to a possibly unreliable 3rd party.

- I don't want to make the call-back synchronously with the web-request, so I want to use a thread-pool.
- I typically get a couple of these a minute so I don't want to have a `newFixedThreadPool(...)` with a large number of threads that mostly are dormant.
- Every so often I get a burst of this traffic and I want to scale up the number of threads to some max value (let's say 50).
- I need to make a *best* attempt to do all callbacks so I want to queue up any additional ones above 50.  I don't want to overwhelm the rest of my web-server by using a `newCachedThreadPool()`.

How can I work around this limitation in `ThreadPoolExecutor` where the queue needs to be bounded and full *before* more threads will be started?  How can I get it to start more threads *before* queuing tasks?

**Edit:**

@Flavio makes a good point about using the `ThreadPoolExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)` to have the core threads timeout and exit.  I considered that but I still wanted the core-threads feature.  I did not want the number of threads in the pool to drop below the core-size if possible.

Comment: Given that your example creates a maximum of 10 threads, is there any real savings in using something that grows/shrinks over a fixed-sized thread pool?

Comment: Good point @bstempi.  The number was somewhat arbitrary.  I've increased it in the question to 50.  Not precisely sure how many concurrent threads I actually want working yet now that I have this solution.

Comment: Oh darn! 10 upvotes if I could here, exactly the same position I am into.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**WARNING: This seems to have been invalidated in JDK 21.0.2 because of a change to the `LinkedBlockingQueue.offer()` method but may work again in JDK 21.0.3.**

> How can I work around this limitation in `ThreadPoolExecutor` where the queue needs to be bounded and full before more threads will be started.

I believe I have finally found a somewhat elegant (maybe a little hacky) solution to this limitation with `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  It involves extending `LinkedBlockingQueue` to have it return `false` for `queue.offer(...)` when there are already some tasks queued.  If the current threads are not keeping up with the queued tasks, the TPE will add additional threads.  If the pool is already at max threads, then the `RejectedExecutionHandler` will be called which does the `put(...)` into the queue.

It certainly is strange to write a queue where `offer(...)` can return `false` and `put()` never blocks so that's the hack part.  But this works well with TPE's usage of the queue so I don't see any problem with doing this.

Here's the code:

```
// extend LinkedBlockingQueue to force offer() to return false conditionally
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6903933921423432194L;
    @Override
    public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
        // Offer it to the queue if there is 0 items already queued, else
        // return false so the TPE will add another thread. If we return false
        // and max threads have been reached then the RejectedExecutionHandler
        // will be called which will do the put into the queue.
        if (size() == 0) {
            return super.offer(e);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1 /*core*/, 50 /*max*/,
        60 /*secs*/, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        try {
            // This does the actual put into the queue. Once the max threads
            //  have been reached, the tasks will then queue up.
            executor.getQueue().put(r);
            // we do this after the put() to stop race conditions
            if (executor.isShutdown()) {
                throw new RejectedExecutionException(
                    "Task " + r + " rejected from " + e);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

With this mechanism, when I submit tasks to the queue, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` will:

1. Scale the number of threads up to the core size initially (here 1).
2. Offer it to the queue.  If the queue is empty it will be queued to be handled by the existing threads.
3. If the queue has 1 or more elements already, the `offer(...)` will return false.
4. If false is returned, scale up the number of threads in the pool until they reach the max number (here 50).
5. If at the max then it calls the `RejectedExecutionHandler`
6. The `RejectedExecutionHandler` then puts the task into the queue to be processed by the first available thread in FIFO order.

Although in my example code above, the queue is unbounded, you could also define it as a bounded queue.   For example, if you add a capacity of 1000 to the `LinkedBlockingQueue` then it will:

1. scale the threads up to max
2. then queue up until it is full with 1000 tasks
3. then block the caller until space becomes available to the queue.

Also, if you needed to use `offer(...)` in the
`RejectedExecutionHandler` then you could use the `offer(E, long, TimeUnit)` method instead with `Long.MAX_VALUE` as the timeout.

**Warning:**

If you expect tasks to be added to the executor *after* it has been shutdown, then you may want to be smarter about throwing `RejectedExecutionException` out of our custom `RejectedExecutionHandler` when the executor-service has been shutdown.  Thanks to @RaduToader for pointing this out.

**Edit:**

Another tweak to this answer could be to ask the TPE if there are idle threads and only enqueue the item if there is so.  You would have to make a true class for this and add `ourQueue.setThreadPoolExecutor(tpe);` method on it.

Then your `offer(...)` method might look something like:

1. Check to see if the `tpe.getPoolSize() == tpe.getMaximumPoolSize()` in which case just call `super.offer(...)`.
2. Else if `tpe.getPoolSize() > tpe.getActiveCount()` then call `super.offer(...)` since there seem to be idle threads.
3. Otherwise return `false` to fork another thread.

Maybe this:

```
int poolSize = tpe.getPoolSize();
int maximumPoolSize = tpe.getMaximumPoolSize();
if (poolSize >= maximumPoolSize || poolSize > tpe.getActiveCount()) {
    return super.offer(e);
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Note that the get methods on TPE are expensive since they access `volatile` fields or (in the case of `getActiveCount()`) lock the TPE and walk the thread-list.  Also, there are race conditions here that may cause a task to be enqueued improperly or another thread forked when there was an idle thread.

Comment: I also struggled with same problem, ended up in overriding execute method. But this is really a nice solution. :)

Comment: As much as I don't like the idea of breaking the contract of `Queue` in order to accomplish this, you're certainly not alone in your idea:  http://groovy-programming.com/post/26923146865

Comment: Interesting.  FYI.  I've actually just improved my method @bstempi per Ralf's feedback.

Comment: Don't you get an oddity here in that the first couple of tasks will be queued, and only after that new threads spawn?  For instance, if your one core thread is busy with a single long-running task, and you call `execute(runnable)`, then `runnable` is just added to the queue.  If you call `execute(secondRunnable)`, then `secondRunnable` is added to the queue.  But now if you call `execute(thirdRunnable)`, then `thirdRunnable` will be run in a new thread.  The `runnable` and `secondRunnable` only run once `thirdRunnable` (or the original long-running task) are finished.

Comment: Yep, Robert is right, in a highly-multithreaded environment, queue sometimes grows while there are free threads to use. The solution below which extends TPE - works much better. I think Robert's suggestion should be marked as answer, even though the above hack is interesting

Comment: I think this answer can be fixed by using Java 7 `LinkedTransferQueue`, with `offer()` calling `tryTransfer()`; I added [yet another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24493856/394431) showing how to do that.  @SemenSemenych, I'd be curious to know how that compares in your tests.

Comment: @Gray In terms of Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor won't the configuration same as:                                                                             ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(1);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();

Comment: They do set the capacity on the queue but the 2nd thread will be created only when the queue is full @Lucky so the same problem exists there.

Comment: @Gray I have the queue capacity as 1. So won't it have the same effect. As the queue capacity is only 1 it will start creating the new thread after capacity is full i.e 1.

Comment: Sure @Lucky.  But to be explicit, it won't create the 2nd thread until the 3rd item is added to the pool.

Comment: I also added this to a answer below which has the same issue. There is an issue when the pool grows up to the maximum size. Say pool scaled up to the maximum size and every thread is currently executing a task, when runnable submitted this offer impl will return false and ThreadPoolExecutor tries to addWorker thread, but pool already reached it's maximum so runnable will simply get rejected. As per the rejectedExceHandler you wrote it will be offered in to the queue again resulting this monkey dance happen from the beginning again.

Comment: No.  When the `RejectedExecutionHandler` is called it just calls `put()` on the queue which will hang @Sudheera.  It won't start the "dance" again.

Comment: The "RejectedExecutionHandler" helped executor at shutdown. Now you are being forced to use shutdownNow() as shutdown() doesn't prevent new tasks to be added (because of reque)

Comment: Interesting @RaduToader.  Never thought about that before.  You are only "forced" to use `shutdownNow()` if clients were going to be adding tasks to the TPE after it is shutdown.  But I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 41):

Set core size and max size to the same value, and allow core threads to be removed from the pool with `allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)`.

Comment: +1 Yeah I thought of that but I still wanted to have the core-threads feature.  I didn't want the thread pool to go to 0 threads during dormant periods.  I'll edit my question to point that out.  But excellent point.

Comment: Thank you! It's just the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 37):

I've already got two other answers on this question, but I suspect this one is the best.

It's based on the technique of [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19528305/394431), namely:

1. Override the queue's `offer()` method to (sometimes) return false,
2. which causes the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to either spawn a new thread or reject the task, and
3. set the `RejectedExecutionHandler` to *actually* queue the task on rejection.

The problem is when `offer()` should return false.  The currently accepted answer returns false when the queue has a couple of tasks on it, but as I've pointed out in my comment there, this causes undesirable effects.  Alternately, if you always return false, you'll keep spawning new threads even when you have threads waiting on the queue.

The solution is to use Java 7 [`LinkedTransferQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html) and have `offer()` call `tryTransfer()`.  When there is a waiting consumer thread the task will just get passed to that thread.  Otherwise, `offer()` will return false and the `ThreadPoolExecutor` will spawn a new thread.

```
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue<Runnable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
            return tryTransfer(e);
        }
    };
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 50, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
    threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            try {
                executor.getQueue().put(r);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have to agree, this looks cleanest to me.  The only downside with the solution is that LinkedTransferQueue is unbounded so you don't get a capacity-bounded task queue without extra work.

Comment: There is an issue when the pool grows to the maximum size. Say pool scaled up to the maximum size and every thread is currently executing a task, when runnable submitted this offer impl will return false and ThreadPoolExecutor tries to addWorker thread, but pool already reached it's maximum so runnable will simply get rejected. As per the rejectedExceHandler you wrote it will be offered in to the queue again resulting this monkey dance happen from the beginning again.

Comment: @Sudheera I believe you are mistaken.  `queue.offer()`, because it is actually calling [`LinkedTransferQueue.tryTransfer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html#tryTransfer(E)), will return false and not enqueue the task.  However the `RejectedExecutionHandler` calls [`queue.put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html#put(E)), which does not fail and does enqueue the task.

Comment: @RobertTupelo-Schneck extremely useful and nice!

Comment: @RobertTupelo-Schneck Works like a charm! I dont know why there is not something like that out of the box in the java

Answer (score 7):

We have a subclass of `ThreadPoolExecutor` that takes an additional `creationThreshold` and overrides `execute`.

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    super.execute(command);
    final int poolSize = getPoolSize();
    if (poolSize < getMaximumPoolSize()) {
        if (getQueue().size() > creationThreshold) {
            synchronized (this) {
                setCorePoolSize(poolSize + 1);
                setCorePoolSize(poolSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

maybe that helps too, but yours looks more artsy of course…

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the this.  I actually did not know that the core size was mutable.

Comment: Now that I think about it some more, this solution is better than mine in terms of checking the size of the queue.  I've tweaked my answer to have the `offer(...)` method only return `false` conditionally.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Note: I now prefer and recommend [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493856/394431).

Here's a version which feels to me much more straightforward: Increase the corePoolSize (up to the limit of maximumPoolSize) whenever a new task is executed, then decrease the corePoolSize (down to the limit of the user specified "core pool size") whenever a task completes.

To put it another way, keep track of the number of running or enqueued tasks, and ensure that the corePoolSize is equal to the number of tasks as long as it is between the user specified "core pool size" and the maximumPoolSize.

```
public class GrowBeforeQueueThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private int userSpecifiedCorePoolSize;
    private int taskCount;

    public GrowBeforeQueueThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        userSpecifiedCorePoolSize = corePoolSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        synchronized (this) {
            taskCount++;
            setCorePoolSizeToTaskCountWithinBounds();
        }
        super.execute(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable runnable, Throwable throwable) {
        super.afterExecute(runnable, throwable);
        synchronized (this) {
            taskCount--;
            setCorePoolSizeToTaskCountWithinBounds();
        }
    }

    private void setCorePoolSizeToTaskCountWithinBounds() {
        int threads = taskCount;
        if (threads < userSpecifiedCorePoolSize) threads = userSpecifiedCorePoolSize;
        if (threads > getMaximumPoolSize()) threads = getMaximumPoolSize();
        setCorePoolSize(threads);
    }
}
```

As written the class doesn't support changing the user specified corePoolSize or maximumPoolSize after construction, and doesn't support manipulating the work queue directly or via `remove()` or `purge()`.

Comment: I like it except for the `synchronized` blocks.  Can you call through to the queue to get the number of tasks.  Or maybe use an `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid them, but the problem is this.  If there are a number of `execute()` calls in separate threads, each is going to (1) figure out how many threads are needed, (2) `setCorePoolSize` to that number, and (3) call `super.execute()`.  If steps (1) and (2) are not synchronized, I'm not sure how to prevent an unfortunate ordering where you set the core pool size to a lower number after a higher number.  With direct access to the superclass field this could be done using compare-and-set instead, but I don't see a clean way to do it in a subclass without synchronization.

Comment: I think the penalties for that race condition are relatively low as long as the `taskCount` field is valid (i.e. a `AtomicInteger`).  If two threads recalc the pool-size immediately after each other, it should get proper values.  If the 2nd one shrinks the core threads then it must have seen a drop in the queue or something.

Comment: Sadly I think it's worse than that.  Suppose tasks 10 and 11 call `execute()`.  Each will call `atomicTaskCount.incrementAndGet()` and they will get 10 and 11 respectively.  But without synchronization (over getting the task count and setting the core pool size), you could then get (1) task 11 sets the core pool size to 11, (2) task 10 sets the core pool size to 10, (3) task 10 calls `super.execute()`, (4) task 11 calls `super.execute()` and is enqueued.

Comment: I gave this solution some serious testing and it's clearly the best. In highly-multithreaded environment it will still sometimes enqueue when there are free threads (due to free-threaded TPE.execute nature), but it happens rarely, as opposed to the marked-as-answer solution, where race condition has more chances to happen, so this happens pretty much on each multi-threaded run.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended answer resolves only one (1) of the issue with the JDK thread pool:

1. JDK thread pools are biased towards queuing. So instead of spawning a new thread, they will queue the task. Only if the queue reaches its limit will the thread pool spawn a new thread.
2. Thread retirement does not happen when load lightens. For example if we have a burst of jobs hitting the pool that causes the pool to go to max, followed by light load of max 2 tasks at a time, the pool will use all threads to service the light load preventing thread retirement. (only 2 threads would be needed…)

Unhappy with the behavior above, I went ahead and implemented a pool to overcome the deficiencies above.

To resolve 2) Using Lifo scheduling resolves the issue. This idea was presented by Ben Maurer at ACM applicative 2015 conference:
[Systems @ Facebook scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlixGkelP9U&feature=youtu.be&list=PLn0nrSd4xjjZoaFwsTnmS1UFj3ob7gf7s)

So a new implementation was born:

[LifoThreadPoolExecutorSQP](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/src/main/java/org/spf4j/concurrent/LifoThreadPoolExecutorSQP.java)

So far this implementation improves async execution perfomance for [ZEL](http://zolyfarkas.github.io/spf4j/spf4j-zel/index.html).

The implementation is spin capable to reduce context switch overhead, yielding superior performance for certain use cases.

Hope it helps...

PS: JDK Fork Join Pool implement ExecutorService and works as a "normal" thread pool, Implementation is performant, It uses LIFO Thread scheduling, however there is no control over internal queue size, retirement timeout..., and most importantly tasks cannot be interrupted when canceling them

Comment: Too bad that this implementation has so much external dependencies. Making it useless for me :-/

Comment: It's a really good point (2nd). Unfortunately, the implementation isn't clear from external dependencies, but still can be adopted if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I now prefer and recommend [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493856/394431).

I have another proposal, following to the original idea of changing the queue to return false.  In this one all tasks can enter the queue, but whenever a task is enqueued after `execute()`, we follow it with a sentinel no-op task which the queue rejects, causing a new thread to spawn, which will execute the no-op immediately followed by something from the queue.

Because worker threads may be polling the `LinkedBlockingQueue` for a new task, it's possible for a task to get enqueued even when there's an available thread.  To avoid spawning new threads even when there are threads available, we need to keep track of how many threads are waiting for new tasks on the queue, and only spawn a new thread when there are more tasks on the queue than waiting threads.

```
final Runnable SENTINEL_NO_OP = new Runnable() { public void run() { } };

final AtomicInteger waitingThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);

BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
        // offer returning false will cause the executor to spawn a new thread
        if (e == SENTINEL_NO_OP) return size() <= waitingThreads.get();
        else return super.offer(e);
    }

    @Override
    public Runnable poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            waitingThreads.incrementAndGet();
            return super.poll(timeout, unit);
        } finally {
            waitingThreads.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Runnable take() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            waitingThreads.incrementAndGet();
            return super.take();
        } finally {
            waitingThreads.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }
};

ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 50, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue) {
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        super.execute(command);
        if (getQueue().size() > waitingThreads.get()) super.execute(SENTINEL_NO_OP);
    }
};
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        if (r == SENTINEL_NO_OP) return;
        else throw new RejectedExecutionException();            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I can think of is to extend.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` offers a few hook methods:  `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute`.  In your extension you could maintain use a bounded queue to feed in tasks and a second unbounded queue to handle overflow.  When someone calls `submit`, you could attempt to place the request into the bounded queue.  If you're met with an exception, you just stick the task in your overflow queue.  You could then utilize the `afterExecute` hook to see if there is anything in the overflow queue after finishing a task.  This way, the executor will take care of the stuff in it's bounded queue first, and automatically pull from this unbounded queue as time permits.

It seems like more work than your solution, but at least it doesn't involve giving queues unexpected behaviors.  I also imagine that there's a better way to check the status of the queue and threads rather than relying on exceptions, which are fairly slow to throw.

Comment: I am not fond of this solution.  I am pretty sure that ThreadPoolExecutor was not designed for inheritance.

Comment: There's actually an example of an extension right in the JavaDoc.  They state that most will probably just implement the hook methods, but they tell you what else you need to look out for when extending.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: For JDK ThreadPoolExecutor** when you have a bounded queue, you are only creating new threads when offer is returning false. You might obtain something usefull with **CallerRunsPolicy** which creates a bit of BackPressure and directly calls run in caller thread.

I need tasks to be executed from threads created by the pool and have an ubounded queue for scheduling, while the number of threads within the pool may **grow** or **shrink** between **corePoolSize** and **maximumPoolSize** so...

I ended up doing a **full copy paste** from **ThreadPoolExecutor** and **change** a bit the execute method because 
**unfortunately** this could not be done by extension(it calls private methods).

I didn't wanted to spawn new threads just immediately when new request arrive and all threads are busy(because I have in general short lived tasks). I've added a threshold but feel free to change it to your needs ( maybe for mostly IO is better to remove this threshold)

```
private final AtomicInteger activeWorkers = new AtomicInteger(0);
private volatile double threshold = 0.7d;

protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    activeWorkers.incrementAndGet();
}
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    activeWorkers.decrementAndGet();
}
public void execute(Runnable command) {
        if (command == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        int c = ctl.get();
        if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
            if (addWorker(command, true))
                return;
            c = ctl.get();
        }

        if (isRunning(c) && this.workQueue.offer(command)) {
            int recheck = this.ctl.get();
            if (!isRunning(recheck) && this.remove(command)) {
                this.reject(command);
            } else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0) {
                this.addWorker((Runnable) null, false);
            }
            //>>change start
            else if (workerCountOf(recheck) < maximumPoolSize //
                && (activeWorkers.get() > workerCountOf(recheck) * threshold
                    || workQueue.size() > workerCountOf(recheck) * threshold)) {
                this.addWorker((Runnable) null, false);
            }
            //<<change end
        } else if (!this.addWorker(command, false)) {
            this.reject(command);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution using two Threadpools both with core and max pool size as same. The second pool is used when the 1st pool is busy.

`import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyExecutor {
    ThreadPoolExecutor tex1, tex2;
    public MyExecutor() {
        tex1 = new ThreadPoolExecutor(15, 15, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
        tex1.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        tex2 = new ThreadPoolExecutor(45, 45, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
        tex2.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    }

    public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor ex = tex1;
        int excessTasks1 = tex1.getQueue().size() + tex1.getActiveCount() - tex1.getCorePoolSize();
        if (excessTasks1 >= 0) {
            int excessTasks2 = tex2.getQueue().size() + tex2.getActiveCount() - tex2.getCorePoolSize();;
            if (excessTasks2 <= 0 || excessTasks2 / (double) tex2.getCorePoolSize() < excessTasks1 / (double) tex1.getCorePoolSize()) {
                ex = tex2;
            }
        }
        return ex.submit(task);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This best earlier answer does not work anymore in JDK 21.0.2, it was working in JDK 21, something has changed internally. I suspect that tryTransfer() does not work in this case.
It seems that Doug Lea broke LinkedTransferQueue:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/8d1ab57065c7ebcc650b5fb4ae098f8b0a35f112

```
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue<Runnable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
                return tryTransfer(e);
            }
        };
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 50, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
        threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                try {
                    executor.getQueue().put(r);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });
```

My workaround is to use normal LinkedBlockingQueue but the following:

```
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        super.execute(command);
//         workaround problem with JDK 21.0.2
        if (!getQueue().isEmpty()) { // if there are items in queue
            int poolSize = getPoolSize();
            if (poolSize < getMaximumPoolSize()) { // if we can add more threads
                int activeCount = getActiveCount();
                if (activeCount >= poolSize) { // if all current threads are active (not idle)
                    synchronized (this) {
                        setCorePoolSize(poolSize + 1); // add new thread
                        setCorePoolSize(poolSize); // this does not remove threads until timeout
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This creates minimum new threads, only if there are items in queue and all current threads are active (not idle).

Comment: You say "this answer does not work anymore".  Do you mean the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, it does not work in JDK 21.0.2, but it works already in Corretto-21.0.2.13.1, so likely it will work again in JDK 21.0.3.

Doug Lea changed LinkedTransferQueue so that offer() is used internally in add() and put(), so that offer() can't be overridden in subclass anymore. This was then fixed in later version.